# Can a 2-DC Cassandra cluster survive a DC outage?

Tags: cassandra

I am building 6 node Cassandra on 2 different data center 3 node each

All 6 nodes will talks to Application layer

If I create a keyspace with replication factor of 3  in case of DC failure ( 3 node down ) can the other 3 node have the full data consistency to serv the application ?

Thx!

n/a

Answer (score 1):

Our recommendation is to configure whichever Cassandra driver you are using to only connect to a "local" DC with queries configured with `LOCAL_QUORUM` for both reads and writes. If the local DC is unavailable for whatever reason, then you should failover to the remote DC.

Our opinion is that it is never a good idea for the drivers to automatically failover from one DC to another so the new default behaviour for the drivers is to only connect to the DC "local" to it.

For more information, see the *Datacenter awareness* section of [Load balancing with DataStax drivers](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dev-app-drivers/docs/loadBalancing.html). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I've done several large cloud deployments like this, and the answer is "yes" a 2-DC Apache Cassandra cluster *can* survive one of its DCs going down.

> it is never a good idea for the drivers to automatically failover from one DC to another

Erick makes a *great* point here.  You won't want your application to talk to both DCs.  What you want, is for your application to be deployed to *both* physical DCs and talk to *only* its "local" DC.  This way you'll take advantage of data locality.

Of course, in that case, losing one DC means that you lose both your app and its DB for that region.  But the other side would still be up.  Whether you'd want to route traffic over to that other region, in that case, is up to you.  But the point is that you'd solve the load balancing / traffic routing above the application; not at the database.

> if any DC goes down the surviving DC cluster will have 100% data to SERV the application ?

As long as both DCs have a defined replication factor in the keyspace definition, then yes, each DC will have 100% of the data.

Comment: The way the app is layout is we have 2 DC Cassandra cluster with 3 nodes each and we have 2 DC App layer talking to the local cassandra cluster, if any DC goes down the surviving DC cluster will have 100% data to SERV the application ?